# I don't understand how v.voronoi GRASS module works with flag -a

Tags: grass-gis, voronoi-thiessen

I'm trying to use v.voronoi with flag -a. An example in the manual shows Voronoi diagram for urban areas but each try returns:

```
v.voronoi -a --overwrite --verbose input=FdT_fromSIE_int_parcelle_culturale_L93_nettoyee@PERMANENT output=test_voonoi_flaga

Reading features... Maximum segment length: 3.26421
ERROR: Found 0 vertices in <FdT_fromSIE_int_parcelle_culturale_L93_nettoyee@PERMANENT>, but at least 2 are needed
```

My input shapefile is type polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run "g.region" beforehand? The [v.voronoi manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.voronoi.html) manual states

"*The bounds of the output map are limited by the current region (see g.region).*"

For an example, see:
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.voronoi.html#voronoi-diagram-for-areas

Comment: 1. example I gave in my question is result of execution under GRASS 7 gui. I don't know how to fix the region in this environmrnt

Comment: 2. implementation in a python script gives very strange result `code` basin_limit = 'basin_limit'
grass.run_command('g.region', flags='sp', vector=basin_limit,
                   stdout = DEVNULL, stderr = DEVNULL)

tmp_voronoi  = 'tmp_voronoi_flaga'
grass.run_command("v.voronoi", input='test_voronoi', output='tmp_wk1',
                               flags='a', 
                               overwrite='True', stdout = DEVNULL, stderr = DEVNULL)  `code`